# C# Object method in separate is not picking up in Main

Tags: c#, math

```
 class Rational
{
    private int Denominator, Numerator;
    public  Rational(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1)
    {
        Numerator = numerator;
        Denominator = denominator;

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Fraction: {0} / {1}", Numerator, Denominator);
    }

    public void IncreaseBy(Rational other)
    {
        Numerator = other.Numerator + Numerator;
        Denominator = other.Denominator + Denominator;
    }
    public void DecreaseBy(Rational other)
    {
        Numerator = Numerator - other.Numerator;
        Denominator = Denominator - other.Denominator;
    }

}
```

This class is a simple one. It is suppose to add or substract a denominator and numerator in my main.

This is in the main, bother under the same namespace
It is suppose to ask the user for the denominator and numerator 4 times. and add them both by 3

```
 class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Print 4 rational numbers.\n");
        do
        {

            Console.Write("Choose a numberator: ");
            int myNumerator = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Choose a denominator: ");
            int myDenominator = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Rational original = new Rational(myNumerator, myDenominator);
            original.IncreaseBy(3, 3);
            Console.WriteLine(original);
            i++;
        } while (i < 4);     


    }
```

Comment: Im very very new

Comment: IncreaseBy is the problem... It gives the red squiggly line

Answer (score 0):

The IncreaseBy method takes one argument, you are giving it two. You need to give it one Rational, so...

```
original.IncreaseBy(new Rational(3, 3));
```